# Publish vs Produce in MassTransit with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit

I want to implement state machine integrated with Kafka topics. Whenever some message will be produced to a topic, I want state machine to react by changing a state. I have two questions:

1. Is producing a message on a topic identical with publishing an event?
2. How to wire things up in a proper way? Some simple code example would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Produce` is not the same as `Publish`. You can use `Produce` to send messages to a topic in Kafka from a state machine:

```
Initially(
    When(Started)
        .Produce(x => x.Init<KafkaMessage>(new {Text = "text"}))
        .TransitionTo(Active));
```

There are unit tests that show how it works, I don't believe it is documented yet. It was added in [this commit](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/commit/f9ad17a47d547fa35c1d27160edbec509e99664b)

Comment: FYI, updated to include the syntax which I merged a couple of weeks ago and forgot!